# qtest: No rule to make target error when compiling test

Tags: qtestlib

I have been working through creating a unit test. I need to learn this to test our gui objects.  So far this site has answered many questions (most were asked and answered previously). However, I am now at a point where I am getting an error and I cannot find a link to help me resolve it. I get "No rule to make target 'TestGui.cpp', needed by 'TestGui.o'. Stop". Can anyone tell me how to fix this and get my test compiled? This is my first attempt at testing...

This is my test file-

```
#include <QString>
#include <QObject>
#include <QtTest>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QApplication>

class SampleTest : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    SampleTest();

private Q_SLOTS:
    void initTestCase();
    void cleanupTestCase();
    void TestGui();
    void TestQstring();
};

SampleTest::SampleTest()
{
}

void SampleTest::initTestCase()
{
}

void SampleTest::cleanupTestCase()
{
}

void SampleTest::TestGui()
{ 
    QLineEdit line_edit;

    QTest::keyClicks(&line_edit, "hello world");

    QCOMPARE(line_edit.text(), QString("hello world"));
}

void SampleTest::TestQstring()
{
    QString str = "hello world";
    QCOMPARE(str.toUpper(), QString("HELLO wORLD"));
}

QTEST_MAIN(SampleTest)

#include "SampleTest.moc"
```

My test.pro file is here -

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2015-09-03T09:46:40
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core widgets gui testlib

TARGET = SampleTest
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += ../sample_project/TestGui.cpp \
            SampleTest.cpp

HEADERS +=  ../sample_project/TestGui.h

FORMS += ../sample_project/TestGui.ui

DEFINES += SRCDIR=\\\"$$PWD/\\\"

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../sample_project

include(../sample_project/sample_project.pri)
```

This is my project .pro file -

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2015-09-03T09:29:42
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = sample_project
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        TestGui.cpp \
    TestBox.cpp

HEADERS  += TestGui.h \
           TestBox.h

FORMS    += TestGui.ui \
       TestBox.ui
```

My project .pri file hs the source and header for my project -

```
SOURCES += TestGui.cpp
HEADRES += TestGui.h
```

Comment: I think it means that TestGui.cpp cannot be found, i.e. there is a path issue. It seems you are running from a different location?

Comment: Thank you.  I just fixed the path issue. The change is reflected above.  However, I still get the error.  I noticed that if I comment out the  last include in my test .pri file it compiles and runs. however, it does not bring up my window from the project. I am trying to bring up the window and key in "hello world" in the lineEdit.

Comment: Ok, I realized that I needed to make similar changes in my project .pri file. It compiles clean, but Now my issue is how do I get it to run the main in my project? I will search for answers on the site. If you have some ideas I would be happy to hear them.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename the class name accordingly to the filename. In your case, SampleTest => TestGui

QtCreator tries to find appropriate class definition. If not, it ignores to create target ".moc:" in projects Makefile.